# How to limit items inside a group in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to select data grouped by `external_id` and `resolution` and ordered by `timestamp` but **limited to first two ids in each group**. I don't know how to do the latter.

I tried to do something with simple query:
`SELECT external_id, resolution, string_agg(id::text, ',') FROM some_table GROUP BY external_id, resolution ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2`
but it's not enough - the limit is applicable to whole query.

### Source

| id | external_id | resolution | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1D | 1645941482 |
| 2 | 1 | 1D | 1645941481 |
| 3 | 1 | 1D | 1645941484 |
| 4 | 2 | 1D | 1645941483 |
| 5 | 2 | 1D | 1645941463 |
| 6 | 3 | 1D | 1645941183 |
| 7 | 3 | 1D | 1645941483 |
| 8 | 3 | 1D | 1646941483 |
| 8 | 3 | 1D | 1645741488 |
| 10 | 3 | 1D | 1645941490 |
| 11 | 1 | 3D | 1645941494 |
| 12 | 1 | 3D | 1645941491 |
| 13 | 2 | 3D | 1645941496 |
| 14 | 2 | 3D | 1645941490 |
| 15 | 2 | 3D | 1645941493 |
| 16 | 2 | 3D | 1645941491 |
| 17 | 3 | 3D | 1645941492 |

### Expected result

| external_id | resolution | ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1D | 1,2 |
| 1 | 3D | 11,12 |
| 2 | 1D | 4,5 |
| 2 | 3D | 13,14 |
| 3 | 1D | 6,7 |
| 3 | 3D | 17 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with cte to select `N` number of rows from any group then you can use `string_agg()` on that result set.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table source(id int, external_id int, resolution varchar(10), timestamp2 timestamp);


 insert into source values(1,   1   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941482));
 insert into source values(2,   1   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941481));
 insert into source values(3,   1   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941484));
 insert into source values(4,   2   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941483));
 insert into source values(5,   2   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941463));
 insert into source values(6,   3   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941183));
 insert into source values(7,   3   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941483));
 insert into source values(8,   3   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1646941483));
 insert into source values(8,   3   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645741488));
 insert into source values(10,  3   ,'1D',  to_timestamp(1645941490));
 insert into source values(11,  1   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941494));
 insert into source values(12,  1   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941491));
 insert into source values(13,  2   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941496));
 insert into source values(14,  2   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941490));
 insert into source values(15,  2   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941493));
 insert into source values(16,  2   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941491));
 insert into source values(17,  3   ,'3D',  to_timestamp(1645941492));
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select id,external_id, resolution, row_number()over(partition by external_id,resolution order by timestamp2)rn from source
 )
 SELECT external_id, resolution, string_agg(id::text, ',') ids
 FROM cte
 where rn<=2
 GROUP BY external_id, resolution
```

Output:

| external_id | resolution | ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1D | 2,1 |
| 1 | 3D | 12,11 |
| 2 | 1D | 5,4 |
| 2 | 3D | 14,16 |
| 3 | 1D | 8,6 |
| 3 | 3D | 17 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d4b676a2f9e7036b78636fe44c009eb4)*

Comment: I had to add `id` to the cte's select, but it returns only one `id` in `string_agg` even if I rise value in the `where` clause

Comment: Sorry for typo. I have already revised my answer.

Comment: You are most welcome @lama. If it helped you then please accept the answer by clicking the green check. Best wishes.